# mongodb- query for finding exact match but not case sensitive - what's wrong with it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

what is wrong with this query ?

```
       db.collection.find( { "name" : "/^test$/i", "group" : "/^Default$/i"} )
```

I am trying to find an object with name=test, group=default, but not case sensitive. 
but I am not getting the result although I know I have this document in the database:

I used exactly as in mongo website it's explained:
In MongoDB, you can also use regular expression objects (i.e. /pattern/) to specify regular expressions:

```
 { <field>: /pattern/<options> }
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: I need to add "$regex"?

Comment: In MongoDB, you can also use regular expression objects (i.e. /pattern/) to specify regular expressions:

{ <field>: /pattern/<options> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query in its essence is right, you just have a minor syntax error.

In javascript (Which Mongo shell is based on) a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is of the form of `/xxx/` and not `"/xxx/"`, the ladder being a `string` expression.

So just change your query into this:

```
db.collection.find( { "name" : /^test$/i, "group" : /^Default$/i} )
```